# Explanation how it can be that $f'(x) = g(x)$ but wolfram alpha says $\int g(x) \neq f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I've just started learning about antiderivatives/primitive functions/indefinite integrals, and I have the functions

$f(x) = 3 \ln((\frac{x+2}{3})^2 + 1)$

$g(x) = \dfrac{2\frac{x+2}{3}}{(\frac{x+2}{3})^2 + 1}$

I came to the conclusion that $f'(x) = g(x)$ so that $\int g(x) = f(x)$ and I wanted to check with wolfram alpha, but wolfram says that [$\int g(x) \neq f(x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=antiderivative++2((x%2B2)%2F3)%2F(((x%2B2)%2F3)**2%2B1)+%3D%3D3+ln(((x%2B2)%2F3)**2+%2B+1)) even though it says [$f'(x) = g(x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+3+ln(((x%2B2)%2F3)**2+%2B+1)+%3D%3D+2((x%2B2)%2F3)%2F(((x%2B2)%2F3)**2%2B1)).

It seems to me that this violates the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative) of antiderivative?

Comment: Note that in general $f'$ doesn't even have to be Riemann integrable, let alone that $\int_0^x f'(t)\,dt = f(x)$. On the other hand, $\int f'$ just denotes the set of antiderivatives of $f'$, which certainly contains $f$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbol $\int g(x) dx$ means the set of all antiderivatives of $g$. Since $f$ is an antiderivative of $g$ , we have

$\int g(x) dx=f(x)+C.$

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x)$ is one of the infinite number of antiderivatives of the function $g(x)$ which differ only by a constant. In the case of $f(x)$, that constant, typically denoted as $C$, is 0. When you integrate $g(x)$, you get a whole set of functions. Not just one function. That set is usually denoted $f(x)+C$ where $C\in\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, this means that there are going to be as many functions in that set as there as real numbers—that is, an infinite number. That's why, technically speaking, $\int g(x)\,dx\neq f(x)$. The result of the integration process is not a function, but a set of functions. Those are slightly different concepts.